# Probability and Random number generator

Tags: c#

I'm working on a problem that involves probability and random number generator that I believe I am close with but need help hammering out one last thing. I have a marble bag in which I will enter the number of marbles that are of different color. Meaning Red 10 green 5 blue 5 orange 3. I have to infer the probability of each colored marble, then randomly generate number of marbles based on that probability. So Far I can calculate the probability as so

```
  int MarbleCnt = red + green + blue + orange;
  double probRed = (double)red / MarbleCnt;
  double probGreen = (double)green / MarbleCnt;
  double probBlue = (double)blue / MarbleCnt;
  double probOrange = (double)orange / MarbleCnt;
```

then I plan to use the `Random().NextDouble` to be used to decipher out which marble was picked this is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    double randNum = mRandom.NextDouble();             
    if (0 <= randNum && randNum < probRed) { probArr[i] = RED_MARBLE; }
    else if (probRed <= randNum && randNum < probGreen) { probArr[i] = GREEN_MARBLE; }
    else if (probGreen <= randNum && randNum < probBlue) { probArr[i] = BLUE_MARBLE; }
    else  { probArr[i] = ORANGE_MARBLE; }
}
```

My issue is what do I do if I have the same number of marbles, Meaning I have 10 red and 5 blue and 5 orange what do I need to do to decipher to pick a blue or an orange.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by: `then randomly generate number of marbles based on that probablity`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I mean I ll calculate the probablity of each colored marble, then use the random generator NextDouble function to generate a number my idea is that if the value gen is greater than the probablitlity than that is the marble I would choose

Comment: Are you interesting in just randomly picking one marble from the bag? Or do you want to be able to randomly pick marbles from the bag one at a time (reducing the count of each marble colour as you go) until it is empty?

Comment: picking one marble out the bag, not reducing it, I have code on how to do that but it doesnt take into account when you have the same number of marbles for two or more colors which is what I am trying to work out

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I wouldn't use `double` at all - I'd just pick a random *integer* between 0 (inclusive) and the total number of marbles (exclusive). Effectively, you'd be "labelling" each marble with a number, and then working out which marble was picked based on the random integer. For example:

```
MarbleColor PickMarble
    (Random rng, int redCount, int greenCount, int blueCount, int orangeCount)
{
    int index = rng.Next(redCount + greenCount + blueCount + orangeCount);
    if (index < redCount)
    {
        return MarbleColor.Red;
    }
    if (index < redCount + greenCount)
    {
        return MarbleColor.Green;
    }
    if (index < redCount + greenCount + blueCount)
    {
        return MarbleColor.Blue;
    }
    return MarbleColor.Orange;
}
```

This is basically the same approach as you've got with doubles, but simpler (IMO) to understand.

Comment: @Arnold That is probability, it is just not the normalized probability. Use the exact same code but use `probRed`, `probGreen`, and `probBlue` and then use `NextDouble()` instead of `Next(MarbleCnt)` (which is what Jon was really using). Think of it as instead of dividing by `MarbleCnt` Jon multiplied the output of `NextDobule()` against `MarbleCnt` instead. Both methods give the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I too would avoid using `double`. While it may seem natural since you are dealing with probabilities you'll find that you end up writing code that becomes difficult to prove the correctness of and to debug.

It's better to try to model the bag of marbles more discretely.

I would do this:

```
var red = 10;
var green = 5;
var blue = 5;
var orange = 2;

var rnd = new Random();

var bag =
    Enumerable.Repeat(RED_MARBLE, red)
        .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(GREEN_MARBLE, green))
        .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(BLUE_MARBLE, blue))
        .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(ORANGE_MARBLE, orange))
        .OrderBy(m => rnd.Next())
        .ToList();
```

I now have a uniformly shuffled bag of marbles which I can pick from to simulate the removal of marbles from the bag.

While this isn't as performant as a purely mathematical approach, it is still incredibly quick. I can produce and sort a bag containing 1.8 **million** marbles in 1 second using this approach.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is currently all of your numbers are between 0 and the normalized (between 0 and 1) probability. Take a look at the values of your prob variables

```
int red = 10;
int green = 5;
int blue = 5;
int orange = 3;
int MarbleCnt = red + green + blue + orange;
double probRed = (double)red / MarbleCnt;
double probGreen = (double)green / MarbleCnt;
double probBlue = (double)blue / MarbleCnt;
double probOrange = (double)orange / MarbleCnt;

Console.WriteLine("Red: " + probRed);       
Console.WriteLine("Green: " + probGreen);       
Console.WriteLine("Blue: " + probBlue);     
Console.WriteLine("Orange: " + probOrange);
```

this outputs

```
Red: 0.434782608695652
Green: 0.217391304347826
Blue: 0.217391304347826
Orange: 0.130434782608696
```

What you need to do is your conditions need to add up the previous conditions, this offsets them and you can tell which "bucket" of probability you landed in.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    double randNum = mRandom.NextDouble();             
    if (randNum < probRed) 
    { 
        probArr[i] = RED_MARBLE; 
    }
    else if (randNum < (probRed + probGreen)) 
    {
        probArr[i] = GREEN_MARBLE; 
    }
    else if (randNum < (probRed + probGreen + probBlue)) 
    {
        probArr[i] = BLUE_MARBLE; 
    }
    else  
    { 
        probArr[i] = ORANGE_MARBLE; 
    }
}
```

If this code looks familiar it is this is exactly what Jon told you to do in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29381137/80274). The step of normalizing the values (dividing by `MarbleCnt`) is unnecessary, instead of normalizing your values between 0 and 1 then picking a random value between 0 and 1 just keep your values 0 to 22 then pick a random number between 0 and 22 instead as Jon described in his answer.

Answer (score -3):

```
char RandomCharacter()
{ 
  /* as the denominator of the probability is 7 hence we will generate a random number between 1-7 */
  int RandNo = rand()%7+1;

  // now distribute the distribution with respect to probability
  if(RandNo<=4 and RandNo>=1) {
    return '*'; // 4/7 chances are to lie here
  }
  if(RandNo<=6) {
    return '#'; // 2/7 chances are to lie in this range now
  } else {
    return '@'; // 1/7 chances are remaining
  }
}
```